# Chromium hacked?

Tags: 12.04, chromium

I have xubuntu 12.04 with chromium 31.0.1650.63 installed.

Occasionally, I will hear a very short audio ad come from my speakers.  This will happen only when Chromium is open, but it will happen when I only have websites up that I am sure do not have audio ads on them.  If I close Chromium, the audio stops.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you have an extension causing this annoyance.

Try disabling one extension at a time to see if this random audio stops playing.

Some users on [the Chrome forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/cXajasuMFwM) attribute the problem to an unofficial Pinterest extension.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try.  (the audio is fairly intermittent, so it will take a while to know for sure if I got it)